# User registration form

Tags: 7, users

I am using drupal 7 built in form name `user_register_form`, when clicked on `submit` or `save` button I want to store the value of `uid` column value  and `status` value (if the request is active or blocked) to be stored in another table? How can I implement this , can anybody please guide me ..

**UPDATED**
My table name is `expiry_user`, `expiry_status` and `expiry_uid` are two columns in my table

```
function mymodule_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category)
{
db_insert('expiry_user')->fields(array(
'expiry_status' => $account['status'],
'expiry_uid' => $account->uid,
))->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [hook_user_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) to take action on the user account after creation:

```
function mymodule_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  //@TODO: use $account->uid & $account->status to do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanku @shawn, I have updated my answer, is this the right way?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there. FYI: you can use [drupal_write_record()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7) instead if you've defined  `expiry_user` with hook_schema.

Comment: I manually created my table in database,as I am using drupal's built in form name `user_register_form` so may I replace the name of my_module in the above function to this form name?

Comment: yes, in order to invoke the hook in your module you need to replace "mymodule" with the machine name of your module.